# How to center a relative div in my case?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create a relative divs with absolute divs inside it.

I also need the relative div being centered on different resolution on desktop and ipad.

I have something like:

```
 <div class='container wrapper'>
        <a id='link1' href='#'><img src='img1.png'/></a>
        <a id='link2' href='#'><img src='img2.png'/></a>
        <a id='link3' href='#'><img src='img3.png'/></a>
        <a id='link4' href='#'><img src='img4.png'/></a>
        <a id='link5' href='#'><img src='img5.png'/></a>
    </div>


.wrapper{
    position: relative;      
    top:10%;
    left:5%;
    height: 800px;
}

#link1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 0;
}
#link2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 350px;
}
#link3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 280px;
    left: 700px;
}
#link4{
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
    left: 580px;
}
#link5{
    position: absolute;
    top: 580px;
    left: 180px;
}
```

I need to use absolute positioning because my elements are not following the regular flows.

they are like

```
      ----
     |    |
     |    |    ---
      ----    |   |
              |   |
 ----          ---
|    |
|    |     ---
 ----     |   |      ---
          |   |     |   |
           ---      |   |
                     ---
```

I am not sure how to see css for my .wrapper div. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: can you explain further? you say you want to center the links but nothing in your css shows attempt to center them..

Comment: I need to center the wrapper that has #link1 to #link5 inside the div.

Comment: I have reedit my question.

Comment: You need just the outside wrapper to be centered relative to the screen? or all links INSIDE to be centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center your `.container` you have to make sure its parent has a set width.  This could be your body tag or a div that is a container.

Then, you can give your container a width and an auto margin like so:

```
.container {
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

`margin:0 auto;` is the same as:

```
margin-top:0;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:auto;
```

If your `.container` is positioned absolutely, you can center it by making sure its parent has a width, then you can do something like this:

```
.container {
    width:960px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-480px; //This is NEGATIVE HALF of the width of the div
}
```

p.s.  Even though it's not a documented thing, usually `.wrapper` is outside of `.container`.  they usually are not the same element.

p.p.s.  You will have to use percentages for your absolute elements so it will scale properly on different devices.  If you have `left:700px`, then it will ALWAYS be 700px from the left.  If it's `left:10%` then it will scale to the width of its container.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if I understand what you need, but I'll try giving you 2 answers.

First and most straight-forward approach will be settings the `width:90%` and `text-align:center`

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;      
    top:10%;
    left:5%;
    height: 800px;
    width:90%;
}
```

add `text-align:center;` if you want the inside elements to be centered;

If you know the div's width, a nice CSS method to center any div with absolute positioning is to set the left to 50% and the margin to 1/2 of the div's width;

```
div {
 position:absolute;
 width:500px;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-250px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your second example needs to make sure the div is `position:absolute;`